# Using a small client to retrieve information using $_GET from database help. PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a database, it works and values have been entered, I have also made a service page using PHP which also works great thanks to a person on here! So I can query that and it works fine e.g.

```
http://localhost/NewWebApp/php/databaseRestService.php?episodename=Pilot
//Outputs: "7th October 2014"
```

Which is correct, however when I use a client (Input field), I get nothing returned. At all. I have gone through all of my code again, and done little if statements to see where the problem could lie, and I have shortlisted it down to my `$data` variable. The code is as follows for this Client.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <?php
    if(isset($_GET["submit1"]))
    {
      $episodeNameForFlash = $_GET["episodename"];

      $url = "http://localhost/NewWebApp/php/databaseRestService.php?episodename ='".$episodeNameForFlash."'";

      $client = curl_init($url);
      curl_setopt($client,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
      $data = curl_exec($client);
      echo curl_error($client);

      if(!$data)
      {
        echo "Error on data";
      }
    }
  ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="databaseRestClient.php" method="GET">
      <label>Enter Name of Episode</label> &nbsp; <input type="text" name="episodename"/>
      &nbsp;
      <input type="submit" name="submit1"/><br/>
    </form>
    <?php
      if(isset($data))
      {
        echo ("The date of the Episode is ". $data);
      }
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thus the output is:    Error on data.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Been trying to figure this out for a couple of hours now.

Kieran

UPDATE: databaseRestService.php code

```
    <?php

  class FlashEpisodes
  {
    var $serverName = "localhost";
    var $userName = "root";
    var $password = "";
    var $databaseName = "test";

    public function FlashEpDate($name)
    {
      $databaseConnection = mysqli_connect($this->serverName, $this->userName, $this->password);

      if(!$databaseConnection)
      {
       // echo "Error";
      }
      if(!mysqli_select_db($databaseConnection, $this->databaseName))
      {
        //echo "Error";
      }
      else
      {
        //echo "Success";
      }

      $sql = "SELECT theFlashEpsDate FROM superhero WHERE theFlashEps ='".$name."'";
      $result = mysqli_query($databaseConnection, $sql);

      if(!$result)
      {
        echo "<br>Error on Query";
      }
      if ($result)
      {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
        $getTheFlashEpsDate = $row[0];
      }
      else
      {
        $getTheFlashEpsDate = null;
      }
      return $getTheFlashEpsDate;
    }
  }

$getEpisodeName = $_GET['episodename'];
$objSuperHero = new FlashEpisodes;
$response = $objSuperHero->FlashEpDate($getEpisodeName);
echo $response;
?>
```

^ The code here works as it should, I can just put in the query in the string and this page works, just when I want to use a client (input field) it does not :(

Comment: Could you post the code generating the error?  databaseRestService.php - EDIT actually, it looks like you're doing a get, try using get_file_contents or printing the URL and entering it into a browser directly

Comment: Sure! Will edit the post now, but on it's own this code works fine and as it should. EDIT: What you have mentioned is what databaseRestService.php actually does, and it also works fine from there, I just want to use a client (input field) to access it instead of the url.

Comment: I see the "echo json_encode($response);" however your statement //Outputs: "7th October 2014" ...  "7th October 2014" is not json, show exactly what the call returns

Comment: @dbinns66 What do you mean? I need that piece of code for the actual output to the screen? Is this the bit that is wrong?

Comment: If your service is returning "7th October 2014" your decode in the client will return an empty string.... you want to make sure it's returning ["7th October 2014"]  though if this is all it's doing, curl and json are a bit of overkill...  I'd pull the json_encode and json_decode and see if it works...  one would mormally encode an array,...

Comment: Okay, how would I go about doing that? And yeah this is all it is doing :)

Comment: Just edited previous comment, just remove the json_encode and json_decode and see if it works

Comment: I removed the json_encode and it outputted the date without the speech marks, however on the Client I remove it json_decode and it outputted this

`Error on data
Enter Name of Episode       
The date of the Episode is`

So it outputted nothing just the echo without the name and still says the error. Thanks for you help though, really appreciate it!

Comment: Did you see my answer below?  If those are the changes you made, add echo curl_error($client); immediately after the curl_exec...  http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: when defining `$url` variable in databaseRestClient.php file, why do you have single quotes for the `$episodeNameForFlash` parameter? I think these single quotes are the cause of the problem, remove them and check your code again. that line sound look like this: `$url = "http://localhost/NewWebApp/php/databaseRestService.php?episodename =".$episodeNameForFlash;`. you may also need to use `urlencode` to encode the `$episodeNameForFlash` variable before using it in the `$url`

Comment: @EhsanT It worked! YES! Thank you ever so much! The reason I put those marks in as that was the solution to get it working for my databaseRestService.php as I got the answer from a fellow member on these forums. It worked without the encoding, however, I have implemented that anyway! Thanks again! If you put up an answer, I will happily accept it for you?

Comment: Sure, I've posted my comment in an answer and thanks

Comment: Done. Thanks for your help and for @dbinns66 for their help too! I've learnt some valuable information for my future development!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when defining `$url` variable in *databaseRestClient.php* file, why do you have **single quotes** for the `$episodeNameForFlash` parameter?
I think these single quotes are the cause of the problem, remove them and check your code again.

that line should look like this:

```
$url = "http://localhost/NewWebApp/php/databaseRestService.php?episodename =".$episodeNameForFlash;
```

it's better for you to use `urlencode` to encode the `$episodeNameForFlash` variable before using it in the `$url` in case of any special characters in the `$episodeNameForFlash` variable and then use `urldecode` in the `databaseRestService.php` file when retrieving the `$_GET['episodename']`

Answer (score 0):

Here's my working version...

```
 <head>
  <?php
    if(isset($_GET["submit1"]))
    {
      $episodeNameForFlash = $_GET["episodename"];

      $url = "http://localhost/testserver.php?episodename ='".$episodeNameForFlash."'";

      $data = file_get_contents($url);

      if(!$data)
      {
        echo "Error on data";
      }
    }  
  ?>   
  </head>
  <body> 
    <form action="testclient.php" method="GET">
      <label>Enter Name of Episode</label> &nbsp; <input type="text" name="episodename"/>
      &nbsp;
      <input type="submit" name="submit1"/><br/>
    </form>
    <?php  
      if(isset($data))
      {
        echo ("The date of the Episode is ". $data);
      }
    ?> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I changed to what you said and I nothing shows on the echo in the client.

`Error on data      
The date of the Episode is`

It doesn't output the date! Thanks for you help!

Comment: add echo curl_error($client); immediately after the curl_exec...  http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: I have added that, but the output is exactly the same with no message showing using curl_erorr. This is how it looks.

`$client = curl_init($url);
      curl_setopt($client,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
      $data = curl_exec($client);
      echo curl_error($client);`

Comment: If it's not working just completely drop the curl and use file_get_contents($url);  I just  tested with your code locally and the file_get_contents works perfectly...  will update my answer

Comment: I have updated to file_get_contents($url); but for some odd reason it is not working for me at all, it still says "Error on data" and "The date of the Episode is" then nothing after, I don't know what is going on what-so-ever...

Comment: @Kieran Lowe - just updated my answer with code that works on my machine

Comment: Thankyou, I have tried that EXACT same code on my machine and still nothing, I still get the same error and says that there is error on data, so I have no idea what I am doing wrong at all. I've been at this for hours now, and I can't get it to work. I added values to my database, created a service which works on it's own and I get the value I want, but AS SOON AS I MAKE A Client for it, it doesn't work. Thanks for all of your help though!